# php doesn't receive encoded $_GET values

Tags: php, curl, get, openssl, urlencode

I have an encrypted with public key and then encoded string, it's something like 200 chars.

```
SENDER:
$pubkey = file_get_contents('http://localhost/test/key.pub');
openssl_public_encrypt('hello world', $encrypted, $pubkey);
$first = $encrypted;
$url = 'http://localhost/demo_project/bank/?secure='.urlencode($first);
echo file_get_contents($url);

RECIEVER:
var_dump($_GET);
```

outputs:

```
array(1) { ["secure"]=> string(0) "" }
```

the secure is `secure=Qq%B8%143%F5%D1%15%C4%18%95g%D6%D0%2F%2CH%25%F8%A8%17%EF%2Bl%80%3Bc%9E%F2%9A%FB%CF3%EDj%B7%26%0F%A0%5E%1DM%AB%07%1Db%0F%C3%9E%A1%FF%82%7D%E50%15Vc%08t%0F%07%0Ag`

the strangest thing is, that if the `secure=Qq%B` , everything works fine, but if `secure=Qq%B8`, we have a problem.

I also tried it with curl like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426124/error-while-using-curl-for-doing-a-post-to-a-certain-api-what-is-the-bug-in-it), but it didn't do any good either. Would someone point me my error and suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [base64](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) *encoding is designed to make binary data survive transport through
>   transport layers that are not 8-bit clean*.

You must encode openssl_public_encrypt()'s binary output data.

Sender:

```
$pubkey = file_get_contents('http://localhost/test/key.pub');
openssl_public_encrypt('hello world', $encrypted, $pubkey);
$first = base64_encode($encrypted);
$url = 'http://localhost/demo_project/bank/?secure='.urlencode($first);
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Receiver:

```
var_dump($_GET);
$secure = base64_decode($_GET['secure']);
```

I'd use `POST`:

```
$url = 'http://localhost/demo_project/bank/';
$postdata = array("secure" => $first);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postdata) );
echo $response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```